# WiX Installer: Modify installation to include package skipped on initial installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, burn

I am building a WiX bundle installer with a managed bootstrapper application. Recently, I added a new `MsiPackage` that installs per-machine, but only installs if the user opts-in via checkbox. The user can modify the installation later from Programs and Features to install this package. This is the only per-machine package in the bundle. The rest are per-user. Allowing installation without elevated privileges is critical for us, which is why this per-machine package is optional. Requesting elevated privileges during modify is fine.

Originally, I configured the new package like so:

```
<MsiPackage Id="optional_package"
            Cache="yes" Compressed="yes" Visible="no"
            DisplayInternalUI="no"
            SourceFile="..\Resources\OptionalPackage.msi" />
```

The problem with this configuration was that, if the package was not installed on first installation of the bundle, it would not be cached (`Cache="yes"` only caches if the package gets installed). If the user then tried to modify the installation to install this package, that operation would fail, since burn could not locate the source of OptionalPackage.msi. I was able to work around this problem by requesting that the package always be cached:

```
<MsiPackage Id="optional_package"
            Cache="always" Compressed="yes" Visible="no"
            DisplayInternalUI="no"
            SourceFile="..\Resources\OptionalPackage.msi" />
```

This fixed the first issue, but produced a new problem. Since OptionalPackage.msi installs per-machine, burn tries to cache it in `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` (per-machine cache) instead of in `%LocalAppData%\Package Cache` (per-user cache). There are two problems with this:

1. `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` is a per-machine location, which requires elevated privileges. Since we always cache this new package, the user always needs elevated privileges to install.
2. During installation, no UAC dialog pops up requesting elevated privileges. Instead the installer fails because it is denied access to `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache`. Running as an administrator is a workaround.

I suspect #2 is a burn bug, since it should be asking for permission to access the per-machine cache. My question is, can I cache to a custom location? Is it possible to force burn to cache per-machine packages to the per-user folder? I do not see any configuration options to do so.

*I tried to provide some context here in case there is a better way to do this. My overall goal is to allow the user to install packages via modify that were skipped on first installation. If there is a better way to do this, please inform me.*

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue, so I thought I'd post an answer here for others to find. I ended up working around the caching problem by downloading the option package on-demand, rather than caching it. Just set `Compressed="no"` and set a `DownloadUrl`.

```
<MsiPackage Id="optional_package"
            Cache="yes" Compressed="no" Visible="no"
            DisplayInternalUI="no"
            SourceFile="..\Resources\OptionalPackage.msi"
            DownloadUrl="https://example.com/download/OptionalPackage.msi" />
```

When the package needs to be installed, WiX will automatically download it. Keep in mind that the file defined by `SourceFile` and that defined by `DownloadUrl` must match exactly. WiX hashes the `SourceFile` and stores that in your installer. It hashes the file at `DownloadUrl` after downloading and will only install it if the hash matches.

This solution wasn't ideal because it requires an interned connection, but there was no other way to satisfy our requirements. Our main issue is that this .msi is a per-machine package and our installer is running per-user. We had a consultation with FireGiant and learned the answer to a few of my other questions above as well:

1. It is not possible to define the cache location for packages from
   within the installer. This can be configured in Windows by a system
   administrator for a user's local machine, but not by us in our
   installer.
2. The fact that WiX did not request elevated privileges in the circumstance I described is indeed a bug in burn.